# Tricky way to register @me account

Tags: icloud, mobileme

I want to register an email address @me.com. Not @icloud.com. It is still possible? Maybe some tricky way? I tried 10.7.2 - before this version is checked @me.com, now does not work. On all of my devices are already iOS 6, so I can't check iOS 5.

Comment: No. The email suffixes are handled server side by Apple. They control domain names and are no longer issuing older ones. You get iCloud or nothing.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? Maybe in a beta version (lion or iOS 5) still work?

Comment: Yes I am sure. Betas aren't up for discussion here (they are bound to strict NDAs) and it doesn't matter what kind of client you use, Apple does it all server side.

Answer (score 5):

Nope. Getting a mobileMe/iCloud email address is handled by Apple from their side. They are no longer supplying `@me.com` email addresses. Now just go to [icloud.com](http://icloud.com).